# android.support.design.button.MaterialButton throws InflateException

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, material-design, android-design-library

I am trying to follow the [The MDC Codelab on codelabs.developers.google.com](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-java/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#1) with the latest library versions.
The **EditText** -`android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText` seems to work as expected however upon using the android.support.design.button.MaterialButton a runtime InflateException is thrown.

### Gradle config:

> compileSdkVersion 28
>
> minSdkVersion 21
>
> targetSdkVersion 28

```
dependencies {
   def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
   def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha05"
   def work_version = "1.0.0-alpha06"
   def supportLibraryVersion = "28.0.0-rc01"

   implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   api "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
   api "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
   api "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
   api "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
   api "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version"

   api ("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion", {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-media-compat'
   })
   api ("com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion", {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-media-compat'
   })
   api ("com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion", {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-media-compat'
   })
   api ("com.android.support:customtabs:$supportLibraryVersion", {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-media-compat'
   })
```

...

### StackTrace

```
    E/XXXXXXApp: Unhandled Exception - Application Crash
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.XXXXXX/com.XXXXXX.activities.XXXXXXActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #84: Binary XML file line #84: Error inflating class android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
    at com.XXXXXXActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:107)
...

 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This component requires that you specify a valid TextAppearance attribute. Update your app theme to inherit from Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
                 at android.support.design.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTextAppearance(ThemeEnforcement.java:170)
                 at android.support.design.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:75)
                 at android.support.design.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:140)
                 at android.support.design.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:133)
```

**EDIT:**
Added more details to stacktrace and figured out that the problem was to do with the fact that the App Theme needs to be inherited from Theme.MaterialComponents.

Comment: post your whole crash logs and XML

Comment: @prashant17 added more details and found the solution too. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56822378/7254873

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Ensure that the App Theme style is inherited from `Theme.MaterialComponents`

Example:

```
<style name="XXXXXAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: There's more information about these errors on the getting started guide: https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/

Comment: that's easier said than done - I'm using the DayNight theme

Answer (score 33):

If you cannot (yet) change the theme for the whole app you can also do it just for `this` view:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/fooButon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:padding="8dp"
==> android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/base_white" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from adding Theme.MaterialComponents

1)you can also add Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge if you only want to get atrributes and not default styling

2)Add androidx and com.google.android.material libraries instead of changing the themes.

More info can be found [(5) The Components of Material Design (Android Dev Summit '18) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPH3F0v1jB0&t=1479s) at 3:25 min

Comment: None of these options fixed the problem for me, while Ciprian's answer did fix the option: apply the theme directly to the component.

Answer (score 1):

The error may also occur when using any Material Components versions starting from 1.0.0 up to the latest, caused by a theme naming conflict because of themes specified in external libraries, such as [Mobile FFmpeg](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg). In this case you need to change the name of your own theme. For further information I explain this in more detail in an answer to this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57565773/2964379

Basically if you encounter this problem, but know that you are correctly using a MaterialComponents theme, do a search in Android Studio for your app theme using "Find in Path" -> "Scope" -> "All Places". For example, after building and running your app, if your theme name is `AppTheme`, search for `"AppTheme"` including the quotes to see if there is a cached XML file that specifies the exact same name.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to make changes to the app's whole theme and answer no. 2 makes your button disappear, then I suggest adding this to your MaterialButton

> android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar"