# Buttons look ugly in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this main layout. It should display 3 buttons, but I am showing you only 1 button definition in order not to put mostly code in the question.The other buttons have the same definition.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="70dp"
    android:paddingBottom="70dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="50dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRfid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/main_button_background"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="@string/button_rfid"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_rfid"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the main_button_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#949597"
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

This is how I see it in design editor of Android Studio:

[image: design editor]

However, this is how it is viewed in the emulator:

[image]

Why are text rendered that way? Is something missing?

By reading tutorials, I don't see anything special in the button definition.

Regards
Jaime

Comment: Why are you using these old style button backgrounds? You can use new Material Buttons. https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/

Comment: @SumitShukla will that work in Android 5?

Comment: Yes ofcourse...

Comment: @jstuardo have you tried `android:includeFontPadding`?

Answer (score 0):

1) Migrate your project to `androidx`.
2) Include dependency in your `build.gradle`:

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

3) Use in your layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
  android:id="@+id/material_icon_button"
  style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/icon_button_label_enabled"
  app:icon="@drawable/icon_24px"/>
```

4) Don't forget to change your applevel theme to Material Component theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

Comment: It’s actually **required** to migrate to AndroidX if you use the `com.google.android.material:material` dependency, unless you’re using the Design Support Library `28.0.0`, which is the last version available.