# Changing button background when clicking hangs

Tags: android

I have buttons that change background when pressed. However, sometimes they "hang", by which I mean they switch to the pressed background without problem, but then stay in the pressed background for sometime even after the button is no longer pressed. The code for the background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/main_button_background_pressed"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/main_button_background_unpressed"/>
</selector>
```

I do not think that there is a problem with the background code, but in that the function that the button triggers is somewhat slow (starting a new Activity). I say this because there are other buttons using the same selector drawable and have no such issue. Is there anyway to prevent this from occurring?

Comment: Don't use these old styles for buttons!! Check out this :https://stackoverflow.com/a/56822378/7254873

Comment: Is it verified that the newer style will solve the issue? It seems like somewhat of a hassle in order to switch to the newer style, when I am totally satisfied with the appearance of the buttons.

Comment: There will be sweet ripple effect on button very quickly that's why i said it. You don't have to wait to see the effect taking place.It's a matter of milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start an activity with delay of 5 seconds.

Comment: Why would that help in this case? I do not want to artificially delay my users, and I don't see why that would help the button delay.

Comment: Maybe your activity is doing heavy works, try with new button and check the opening time. Even its slow with new button means, starting activity is a problem