# Weird button on different devices

Tags: android, button

I have an app with a button with a drawable at the left

Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myLL"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LocationsActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddLoc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/plus_vector"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/plus_vector"
        android:drawablePadding="20dp"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="ADD LOCATION"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#1B9EAF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvLoc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The button looks good on most of the devices and looks like this
[image]

But on a few lets say old devices, the button looks like this

[image]

What can be a possible cause and solution for the same?

Comment: Use any one from this two properties ,  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/plus_vector"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/plus_vector"

Answer (score 0):

> Don't use these old style buttons make use of Material Buttons: See
>   here [Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56822378/7254873)

**You should use Icon Button**

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Icon Button"
        app:icon="@drawable/your_icon"
        app:iconGravity="start"/>
```